# Ploting Matplotlib plots in pyqt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to plot matplotlib plots in pyqt5 windows with navigation toolbar in order to show the next image on click using Figure Canvas. However the code is giving "image cannot converted to float" error on axes.plot. The data is coming from the csv which is then plotted using matplotlib.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

df=pd.read_csv('Trump.csv')

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


    self.figure = plt.figure()
    self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
    #self.axes.hold(False)
    self.axes.clear()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

    self.canvas.setParent(self)

    self.canvas.move(100,20)
    self.canvas.hide()
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
    self.toolbar.hide()


    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

  def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.show()

 def show(self):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(random_state=21, max_font_size=110).generate(str(df['Tweets']))
    plot2= plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")        
    self.canvas.show()
    self.axes.imshow(plot2)
    self.canvas.draw()

    self.setScene(scene)

    plot3=sns.countplot(x = 'Vader', data = df)
    self.canvas.show()
    self.axes.imshow(plot3)
    self.canvas.draw()

    self.setScene(scene)

    #self.graphicsView.addItem((plt.imshow(wordcloud)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MainWindow()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: share the .csv.....

Comment: Thanks Bro! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qSHDaMu2kw8Xzb7oLlhv42hoKwCfAhGg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use matplotlib with Qt you don't have to use pyplot but the axes.

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from wordcloud import WordCloud
import pandas as pd


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)
        self.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot()

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(current_dir, "Trump.csv"))
        wordcloud = WordCloud(random_state=21, max_font_size=110).generate(
            str(df["Tweets"])
        )
        self.axes.imshow(wordcloud)

        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I plot two graphs and swipe them from the navigation toolbar?